# Add a new sub menu to compare with menu in Package explorer and project explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to add a new command to "compare with" menu present in context menu of Package Explorer and Project Explorer.
Command is getting displayed only in Package Explorer. I am not getting any command in Project Explorer. I want the command to be present only in these two views. 
Below is my code.

```xml
<menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer?after=additions">
         <menu
               id="compareWithMenu"
               label="Compare With">
            <separator
                  name="compareWithGroup">
            </separator>
         </menu>
</menuContribution>
<menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer?after=additions">
         <menu
               id="compareWithMenu"
               label="Compare With">
            <separator
                  name="compareWithGroup">
            </separator>
        </menu>
</menuContribution>

<menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:compareWithMenu?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="com.test.compareWithEachOther"               
               label="Compare with each other"               
               style="push">
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="true">
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
</menuContribution>
<menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:compareWithMenu?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="com.test.compareWithEachOther"             
               label="Compare with each other"               
               style="push">
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="true">
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
</menuContribution>
```

I tried changing my id menu contribution also. But then in Package Explorer a new compare with option is coming. I think this is expected.
I want the command to be present only in these two views.
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup menu id for Project Explorer appears to be

```
org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu
```

Alternatively the PDE plugin uses:

```xml
<menuContribution
       allPopups="false"
       locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
```

to add its 'Compare With > API Baseline' menu item.

Comment: Thanks you very much for editing my question. I am still in the learning phase in Eclipse RCP and thanks for the answer. It is working fine now. There was only ID mismatch.